# using poweriso cmd commands from c sharp code

Tags: c#

I am making a `C#` program that will make input file an `.iso` file.

For example if we write `C:\Users\User\Desktpo\a.txt` in the `textbox` that I created and give a destination path for example `C:\` it has to create an `iso` file name `a` in `C:\`.

So I downloaded `PowerISO` and learn about `piso.exe` then I made some other research about using `Process.Start();` in `C#` so I write these lines of code:

```
string str = " create -o " + TextBox1.Text + ".iso -add " + TextBox2.Text + "//" ;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\PowerISO\piso.exe\"";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = str;
process.Start();
```

But this doesn't work.
Why?

EDIT: I am making an `winform` using `Visual Studio 2017`.

Comment: Can you debug and tell us if it is triggering an exception?

Comment: Try removing the space at the start of your str, and remove the quotes in the filename.

Comment: a) it doesnt trigger and exception

Comment: b) already tried

Comment: `process.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\PowerISO\piso.exe\"";` this won't even compile

Comment: it does ::::::::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Note that

> C:\PowerISO\piso.exe\

is not a valid C# path, the "\" before the P and the p is an escape indicater.
Either Add verbatim operator "@" before or escape it properly

edit: 
In addition, you are adding **extra** double quotes to the FileName property.
You can check if the path is correct by asserting the file path with File.Exists method

```
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(@"C:\PowerISO\piso.exe") ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

e.g

```
           string str = " create -o " + TextBox1.Text + ".iso -add " + TextBox2.Text + "//" ;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PowerISO\piso.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = str;
            process.Start();
```

edit:
Verbatim operator will work, but escaping is better in my opinion.

```
           string str = " create -o " + TextBox1.Text + ".iso -add " + TextBox2.Text + "//" ;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\PowerISO\\piso.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = str;
            process.Start();
```

Comment: still nothing  WWW

Comment: still nothing is there another way to do it

Comment: Try doing the following.
File.Exists(<poweriso path>)

Comment: Wait, Why are you wrapping he FileName path with extra double quotes.
it should be
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\PowerISO\\piso.exe";

Comment: What was the solution?